# Make last column take all remaining space in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to create a table using `longtable` where all columns have a fixed length except the last one, which should take all remaining space. The table itself should be full page width.

I tried the following with `longtable`, but it is not working:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[h]{p{2cm}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
\toprule
Icon   & Description \\
\midrule
Icon 1 & Means this and that \\
Icon 2 & Means some other thing \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

With `tabu` I would achieve something like this as follows:

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {p{2cm}X}
```

Here's an online example: https://es.sharelatex.com/project/555e01773b14e98f7d55ed84

How to do the same using `longtable`?

**Edit:** I know I can do this with other environments. The question is specifically whether this can be achieved with `longtable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I need by just adding an additional, "dummy" column. Just changing this:

```
\begin{longtable}[h]{p{2cm}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
```

to this:

```
\begin{longtable}[h]{p{2cm}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
```

seems to do the trick.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` in `tabularx` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ nomarginpar]{geometry}%showframe,
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2cm}>{\arraybackslash}X}
  \caption{A demo of the possibilities of \texttt{ltablex}}
  \\ \toprule
  Icon & Description\medskip
  \endfirsthead
  \midrule
  Icon & Description\medskip% \
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot%\\
         & \lipsum[1] \\
  \midrule
  Icon 1 & Means this and that \lipsum[2] \\
  Icon 2 & Means some other thing\lipsum[3] \\
  Icon 3 & Means this and that \lipsum[4] \\
  Icon 4 & Means some other thing\lipsum[5]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There are also other options such as `longtabu`. However I am looking for a way to achieve this with `longtable` ...

Comment: s I said `latablex` combines `longtable` and `tabularx` (and loads both). See my updated answer for a demo.

Comment: Yes I know what you said but I cannot use `ltablex` (these tables are generated by an external tool which uses `longtable`)

Comment: You just have to replace the name of the environment and the preamble of the tables. That shouldn't be too hard, I guess. If there are many of them, search and replace with regular expressions should do it easily.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now, but it introduces an extra step in the build process which I want to avoid. Hence my question: Can the same effect be achieved with `longtable`.

Comment: The only way I see consists in computing yourself the width of the last column. So you won't have to replace the name of the environment, but you'll still have to replace the specifier of the last column. The advantage of  `ltablex` is it computes it for you.

Comment: I knew there had to be another way, and just found a solution after playing a bit more with `longtable`. See my answer.

Comment: @Grodriguez: It's fine, but you can't have line breaks. I don't know if this is required, though.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to achieve this is to use `ltxtable` where [long table meets tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable).  The interface is different from `tabu`, the command `\LTXtable` reads an external file containing your `longtable`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents,ltxtable}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{longtab.tex}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{2cm}X@{}}
  \toprule
  Icon   & Description \\
  \midrule
  Icon 1 & Means this and that \\
  Icon 2 & Means some other thing \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\LTXtable{1.0\linewidth}{longtab.tex}

\end{document}
```

`ltablex` does not have this restriction (see Bernard's example).  Note that it loads `longtable` and `tabluarx` internally.